# Django Form, make readonly field

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

I'm trying to create a Form with Django and i'm aiming to have a readonly field, without success. The field should contain a code that is calculated in the view but i need to show it to the user.

This is the Model:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True,null=True)
    code = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,unique=True)
```

This is the Form:

```
class NewCustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['name', 'code', 'note']
```

That should be pretty easy but i'm facing a lot of problems. What I've already tryed:

1. Field.disabled = True (the documentation don't explaine where should i put this attribute so maybe i'm getting something wrong)
2. `self.fields['code'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True` in __init __
3. `self.fields['code'].widget.attrs['disabled'] = True` in __init __

In all of three method the field remain editable by the user

Comment: Please add the code of your template where the form is rendered. And the code of your view could be useful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML input will *always* be editable by the user, even if you set `readonly` or `disabled` to true, the user can just remove both of those flags and type in a value!

However, as long as the field renders as `readonly` or `disabled`, and it's apparent to the user that the field is fixed, and your python code sets a fixed value that ignores user input, you should be fine.

Comment: where should I set Field.disabled = True to prevent the field from being processed?

Comment: I would override your `.save()` method to ensure the value is always what you are generating for the user - what you display to the user, should be a readonly field

Answer (score 0):

If the code field value is not needed in the html output, I would suggest to exclude the field from the form and calculate the value in the view of the form is valid.
You can assign the calculated value to the model instance in your view before saving.

```
class YourView(views.CreateView):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.code = your_calculated_value
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: I need to print the value in the form. The value is calculated befor the GET and after a successful POST (basically before every new input)